# Full Archive Node Compaction Performance

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node, archive-node

We're currently syncing a Full Archive Node (`--gcmode archive --sync full --mainnet`) and are experiencing a relatively odd behavior:

[image: blocks processed per second]
[image: chain head]

As you can see, the node seems to "pause" its processing of new blocks regularily. After a bit of investigation, we noticed that it seems to be linked to database compaction:

```
{"database":"/var/lib/geth/geth/chaindata","lvl":"warn","msg":"Database compacting, degraded performance","t":"2021-04-14T09:19:35.407752222Z"}
```

I've found some older resources talking about this behavior:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16871
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17020

We're running `1.10.2 Kepler Verge` with comfortable hardware (2x NVMe disks on RAID-0, 1gbps link, 16 4.5Ghz cores and 64GB RAM) with an average of 4000 peers and a sustained ingress of about 20mbps.

CPU usage sits around 50%, iowait is < 0.1, load average is normal ; geth process doesn't seem to be starving at all.

My questions are relatively simple : is this an expected behavior ? if yes, can we improve resource consumption to speed up the compaction process ?

Thanks a lot.